# How do I cancel a submit event, caused by the press of a ButtonColumn

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

I am using an ASP datagrid, and I have a ButtonColumn. When the button is rendered to the page, it is a input of type submit. So its a submit button. The button is used for deleting records. But I want to have some javascript that confirms that the user wants to delete the record. The problem that I have is that even if I return false from the confirm method, the submit event still happens...

Here is the Server Side Code that assigns the javascript method to the click event:

```
Button deleteButton = e.Item.Cells[6].Controls[0] as Button;
if (deleteButton != null)
{
    deleteButton.OnClientClick = "confirmDelete()";
}
```

Here is the ASP.net code that creates the datagrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid 
    runat="server" 
    ID="UsersList" 
    OnItemCommand="UsersList_ItemCommand" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="dataTableHeader" 
    Width="60%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Username" DataTextField="Username" HeaderText="Username"  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Account/EditUser.aspx?user={0}"/>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:ButtonColumn Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" ButtonType="PushButton" CommandName="DeleteUser" CausesValidation="false" />
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Here is the Javscript code that confirms the delete:

```
<script>
    function confirmDelete() {
        var x = confirm("This action cannot be undone. Are you sure you want to delete this user?");
        return x;
    }
</script>
```

Perhaps there is no way to accomplish this with a ButtonColumn. I'm considering changing to a TemplateColumn, and just putting a button in there. But then I will have to redesign the code that handles these click events on the back end, which is currently handled in the ItemCommand handler.

Comment: Ok, I should have seen this coming. It looks like by replacing the handler for the submit event, I'm somehow erasing what asp.net has going on. Because now when I click the buttons, the ItemCommand method on the C# side doesn't fire. Which tells me that the submit is not informing the server side that it is a postback from an asp.net control... Who loves ASP.net controls..?? NOT THIS GUY!! HTML, JavaScript, and Mountain Dew... WHOOO HOOO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to confirm delete on form.submit(), not deletebutton.click(), but you'll need to either assign an anonymous validation function to form.submit by the deletebutton.click(), or set a delete flag on deletebutton click, then check that value on form.submit(). That way other buttons that you WANT to submit the form still submit. And don't forget to clear the variable/or anon function after validation fails.

Comment: Thanks. I should have pointed out that there are three buttons. Delete, Reset, Unlock. So I may need to set a flag of some sort, then have a function that can switch on flags to determine which button was clicked and thus which confirmation to present.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 deleteButton.OnClientClick = "return confirmDelete()";
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the onclick listener on the button with an onsubmit listener on the form that returns false if you don't want to submit the form, something like:

```
<form onsubmit="return confirmDelete();" ...>
```

If *confirmDelete* returns false, the submit is cancelled. If it returns any other value, the form is submitted.